# Is it possible to set partial class name in classes of ckeditor AllowedContent

Tags: ckeditor

I've seen that it is possible to set partial attribute name in ckeditor allowedContent

such as 
allowedContent: {
    h1: {
        attributes: 'data-*'
    }
}

Is it possible to set such "pattern" to classes as well? I know I can set general '*' and get any class of an element, but can I set class with prefix and then *?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Wildcards are supported in class, attribute and style names.

After [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) documentation:

> - An asterisk used as the only property in the property list means: "Accept all properties".
> - An asterisk used as part of a property name means a wildcard accepting 0 or more characters.
> - A combination of an exclamation mark and a wildcard (e.g.: [!data-*]) means that an element must have at least one data attribute.

Comment: Thanks, it does work for attributes, but it didn't work for me with classes...Does it work for classes as well as attributes? And if so - what is the syntax with objects allowed content?